# Mimimization of anonymous function in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, minimization

I have a cyclic program in C++ which includes composing of a function (every time it is different) and further minimization of it. Composing of a function is implemented with GiNaC package (symbolic expressions).
 I tried to minimize functions using Matlab `fmincon` function but it ate all the memory while converting string to lambda function (functions are rather complicated). And I couldn't manage to export function from C++ to Matlab in any way but as a string. 
Is there any way to compose a complicated function (3 variables, sin-cos-square root etc.) and minimize it without determing gradient by myself because I don't know how functions look before running the program?
I also looked at `NLopt` and as I understood it requires gradients to be writte by programmer.

Comment: Could you give more detail? If the functions are composed with GiNaC, why don't you differentiate them with [it](http://www.ginac.de/tutorial/#Symbolic-differentiation)?

Answer (score 1):

Most optimization algorithms do require the gradient. However, if it's impossible to 'know' it directly, you may evaluate it considering a small increment of every coordinate. If your F function depends on coordinates of `x` vector, you may approximate the i's component of you gradient vector G as

```
x1 = x;
x1[i] += dx;
G[i] = (F(x1) - F(x))/dx;
```

where `dx` is some small increment. Although such a calculation is approximate it's usually absolutely good for a minimum finding provided that `dx` is small enough.